# Filter to retrieve specific value in nested object using Vue

Tags: json, vue.js, object, filter

I have a nested json object:

```
{
  "51": {
    "wheels": 10,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "truck"
  },
  "55": {
    "wheels": 4,
    "id": 33,
    "name": "Car"
  },
  "88": {
    "wheels": 2,
    "id": 90,
    "name": "Bike"
  }
}
```

I  would like to filter by ID but only return the wheels so ie.

Filter ID = 33 which would return 4.

I have tried using the .filter function but I get an error: `filter is not a function` which I assume is because this is not an array. I have tried to replicate using answer here:

[How to filter deeply nested json by multiple attributes with vue/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437593/how-to-filter-deeply-nested-json-by-multiple-attributes-with-vue-javascript)

Without success because the json has a key (51, 55, 88) so I am stumped.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array and then use `find` method on it to retrieve the specific object. Something like:

```
Object.values(obj).find(val => val.id === 33)?.wheels
```

```js
let obj = {
  "51": {
    "wheels": 10,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "truck"
  },
  "55": {
    "wheels": 4,
    "id": 33,
    "name": "Car"
  },
  "88": {
    "wheels": 2,
    "id": 90,
    "name": "Bike"
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(obj).find(val => val.id === 33)?.wheels)
```